# FullCalendar initializing before events load

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a FullCalendar that takes in an `array(selectedEvents)` from a function that uses the `Location ID` that is pulled from the url. The array is built `onInit` as is the calendar but the calendar has a timeout on it in order to allow the events to populate. When the calendar is initially navigated to from another part of the website, the events for the Default Location are not displayed but they are populated into the `selectedEvents` array. When I click on another location's calendar, the events are populated and then displayed correctly. The calendar works correctly thereforth. I believe the calendar is taking precedence over the population of events during the first initialization of the calendar even though it is wrapped in a timeout. I've seen this question once before on SO but it was not answered.

I've already tried extending the timeout of the calendar

```
   getLocationEvents(location: PFLocation) {
    // if (this.allEvents) {
    this.selectedEvents = [];
    if (location.events) {
        console.log(location.events);
        this.eventIdArray = location.events;
        for (let event of this.eventIdArray) {
            this.eventService.get(event).subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.selectedEvents.push(data);
            });
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
    console.log(this.selectedEvents);
    return this.selectedEvents;
}

getBatchEvents(location: PFLocation) {
    var that = this;
    if (this.allEvents) {
        if (location.batches) {
            let batches = location.batches;
            for (let batch of batches) {
                this.batchService.get(batch).subscribe(data => {
                    for (let event of data.events) {
                        this.eventService
                            .get(event)
                            .subscribe(eventData => {
                                console.log(eventData);

                              this.selectedEvents.push(eventData);
                            });
                    }
                });
            }
            console.log(this.selectedEvents);
            console.log('out of Batch Events');
            return this.selectedEvents;
        }
    }
    if (!this.allEvents) {
        this.selectedEvents = [];
        if (location.batches) {
            let batches = location.batches;
            for (let batch of batches) {
                this.batchService.get(batch).subscribe(data => {
                    for (let event of data.events) {
                        this.eventService
                            .get(event)
                            .subscribe(eventData => {
                                console.log(eventData);

                           this.selectedEvents.push(eventData);
                            });
                    }
                });
            }
            console.log(this.batchEvents);
            console.log('out of Batch Events');
            return this.selectedEvents;
        }
    }
}

getAllEvents(location: PFLocation) {
    this.allEvents = true;
    var that = this;
    that.getLocationEvents(location);
    that.getBatchEvents(location);
}

ngOnInit() {
    let that = this;
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.locationId = params['locationid'];
        this.userService
            .getLocation(this.locationId)
            .subscribe(location => {
                console.log('Out of on Init');
                this.selectedLocation = JSON.parse(
                    JSON.stringify(location)
                );
                that.getAllEvents(this.selectedLocation);
                console.log(this.selectedLocation);
            });`enter code here`
        console.log(this.selectedLocation);
        if (this.locationId) {
            const today = new Date();
            const y = today.getFullYear();
            const m = today.getMonth();
            const d = today.getDate();
            $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar(
                'addEventSource',
                that.selectedEvents
                );
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar({
                    viewRender: function(view: any, element: any){
                        // We make sure that we activate the 
                   perfect scrollbar when the view isn't on Month
                        if (view.name != 'month') {
                            var elem = $(element).find('.fc- 
                             scroller')[0];
                            let ps = new PerfectScrollbar(elem);
                        }
                    },
                    header: {
                        left: 'title',
                        center: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
                        right: 'prev, next, today'
                    },
                    defaultDate: today,
                    selectable: true,
                    selectHelper: true,
                    views: {
                        month: {
                            // name of view
                            titleFormat: 'MMMM YYYY'
                            // other view-specific options here
                        },
                        week: {
                            titleFormat: ' MMMM D YYYY'
                        },
                        day: {
                            titleFormat: 'D MMM, YYYY'
                        }
                    },
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when 
                     too many events
                    select: function(start: any, end: any) {
                        that.openEventForm();
                    },
                    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent) {
                        that.completeEventForm(event);
                    }
                });
            }, 500);
        }
    });
}
```

I expect the calendar to be populated the first time I navigate to the page.

Comment: "the calendar has a timeout on it in order to allow the events to populate" ...this could easily be flakey. What happens if the events take longer to populate than normal? Don't rely on a timer, rely on the actual completion of the task. This can be done easily using a callback

Comment: Another thing: when you write `$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar({` this re-creates the calendar again from scratch, destroying the previous instance. Therefore this will destroy any events you may have added to previous instances. not mention, you are setting a timeout to re-create the calendar, but the command to add the event source is not within the time-delayed function so that would run before the timer starts meaning your statement about having a timeout to allow the events to populate is incorrect.And that's before you consider the issue of re-creating the calendar makes that null anyway

Comment: But...I don't really know about what is involved in getting event data from your backend services and so on, but to me what you have shown above is a huge amount of spaghetti code and seemingly masses of complexity for what should be a fairly simple task - i.e. creating or downloading some JSON and loading it into the calendar. in fullCalendar the generally recommended way to load events is to simply specify the event source via a URL and some AJAX options (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed) ....

Comment: ...or, if it's a slightly more complex scenario, via a customisable callback function (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function). In both these cases, you don't wait for the events to load before creating the calendar, instead the calendar gets initialised, and then its first job is to go and fetch event data from the nominated source. Furthermore it will then try to fetch more events from the source whenever the user changes the date range (on the premise that the source will only ever provide events within the specified visible date range when requested, to save unnecessary downloads)

Comment: So in conclusion, I would recommend you re-think your approach and try to simplify that jumble of code. It's hard to untangle everything but unless I'm mistaken it looks like you might have two separate sources of events ("batch" and "location")? In which case see also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventSources and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-source-object

Comment: First of all, I recommend you to use the full calendar angular version https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular

Comment: That's also a good recommendation, although it does mean you would also need to upgrade from fullCalendar 3 to fullCalendar 4 which is a [fairly big change](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'm running through them at the moment but just some additional info..I've tried adding event sources as urls and functions but they don't seem to be recognized. Also, if I wrap the Calendar in another function other than OnInit, It doesn't load.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from refactoring the backend and eliminating the spaghetti code it wasn't a difficult issue once someone pointed out how the calendar inits. First the calendar has to grab onto the DOM element then it grabs the event source. If it doesn't grab the #calendar then it won't grab the event source until the next time it's initialized and at that point it is using the old event source data(if set up as my code was).  "viewRender" needs to happen first, then "removeEvents" then "addEventSource".

```
getLocationEvents(location: PFLocation) {
        if (location.events) {
            return this.eventService
                .getFaciltyTasks(location._id)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.facilityEvents = data;
                });
        }
    }

    getAllBatchEvents(location: PFLocation) {
        return this.eventService
            .getAllCultivationTasks(location._id)
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.cultivationEvents = data;
            });
    }

    getBatchEvents(batchId: string) {
        return this.eventService.getBatchTasks(batchId).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.batchEvents = data;
        });
    }

    editEventForm() {
        this.state = 'editEvent';
    }

    getAllEvents(location: PFLocation) {
        var that = this;
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            return this.eventService
            .getAllLocationTasks(location._id)
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
                that.selectedEvents = data;
                that.calInit();
                resolve(that.selectedEvents);
            });
        });
    }

    calInit() {
        var that = this;
        const $calendar = $('#fullCalendar');
        console.log(that.locationId);
        if (this.selectedEvents) {
            const today = new Date();
            const y = today.getFullYear();
            const m = today.getMonth();
            const d = today.getDate();
            $calendar.fullCalendar({
                viewRender: function(view: any, element: any) {
                    // We make sure that we activate the perfect scrollbar when the view isn't on Month
                    if (view.name != 'month') {
                        var elem = $(element).find('.fc-scroller')[0];
                        let ps = new PerfectScrollbar(elem);
                    }
                },
                customButtons: {
                    filter: {
                        text: 'filter',
                        click: function() {
                            that.open();
                        }
                    }
                },

                // events: that.selectedEvents,
                header: {
                    left: 'title',
                    center: 'filter, month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
                    right: 'prev, next, today'
                },
                defaultDate: today,
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                views: {
                    month: {
                        // name of view
                        titleFormat: 'MMMM YYYY'
                        // other view-specific options here
                    },
                    week: {
                        titleFormat: ' MMMM D YYYY'
                    },
                    day: {
                        titleFormat: 'D MMM, YYYY'
                    }
                },
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                select: function(start: any, end: any) {
                    that.openEventForm();
                },
                eventClick: function(event, jsEvent) {
                    that.eventLocation = new PFLocation({});
                    that.eventBatch = new Batch();
                    that.eventRoom = new Room();
                    that.viewEvent(event);
                }
            });
            $calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', that.selectedEvents);
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // const $calendar = $('#fullCalendar');
        let that = this;
        // that.filter = false;
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            that.locationId = params['locationid'];
            if (that.locationId) {
                that.AuthService.getCurrentUser().then(user => {
                    that.currentUser = user;
                    var locations = that.currentUser.locations.admin.concat(
                        that.currentUser.locations.user
                    );
                    var location = find(locations, function(location) {
                        return location._id == that.locationId;
                    });
                    console.log(location);
                    console.log(that.currentUser);
                });
            }

            this.userService
                .getLocation(this.locationId)
                .subscribe(location => {
                    console.log('Out of on Init');
                    this.selectedLocation = JSON.parse(
                        JSON.stringify(location)
                    );
                    that.getAllEvents(this.selectedLocation);
                    console.log(this.selectedLocation);
                });
            console.log(this.selectedLocation);
        });
    }
```